# Connecting two models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to call value from another model inside the views.

```
tse.headoffice.head_office_id
```

Defined the relationship in headoffice.rb as

```
has_many :tse
```

and in tse.rb as

`belongs_to :headoffice`

Now I am getting an error as undefined method

> undefined method `head_office_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: cross check tse `head_office_id` is nil thats why you are getting this error, you should handle it with `tse.headoffice.present?`

Comment: In your first statement what is `tse` ? Is it an instance of `Tse` ? Try `@tse=Tse.first` `@tse.headoffice.head_office_id` if it fails some data is missing ..

Comment: shouldn't it be just `tse.headoffice_id`?. With `tse.headoffice` you already reached to the `Headoffice` instance, calling `head_office_id` on it doesn't make any sense. Maybe `tse.headoffice.id` ?

Comment: @Maxence It is an instance of Tse.

Comment: @kiddorails The error is cleared, the values dont fetch from the 'headoffice' model.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have a relation with headoffice and tse, with tse `belongs_to` headoffice and headoffice `has_many` tse. In my 'tse' view, I need to show up the Headoffice name and ID / code along with tse name. Now that is throwing the error.

Comment: `tse.name`, `tse.headoffice.name` and `tse.headoffice.id` should suffice, no?

Comment: No I dont think that should work. We will have to specify the exact column name. Again, out of curiosity I tried that too. :P. No luck.

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: Have you tried changing `has_many :tse` to `has_many :tses`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if tse.headoffice.present? %>
  <%= tse.headoffice.head_office_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This one removes the error but the values are not fetching from the db. There are values in headoffice table.

Answer (score 0):

`try()` lets you call methods on an object without having to worry about the possibility of that object being `nil` and thus raising an exception

```
<%= tse.try(:headoffice).try(:head_office_id) %>
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect `tse`, just to make sure the result you are getting? Try `<%= tse.inspect %>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the HeadOffice model has an attribute called `head_office_id`:

```
<%= tse.headoffice.head_office_id if tse.headoffice %>
```

If that's not the case:

```
<%= tse.headoffice_id %>
```

Comment: @vivek-s then perhaps the problem is elsewhere. probably the model isn't being passed correctly through the controller, or you didn't create the model correctly. could you post the controller code? an example showcasing an example of a real model stored in the DB with its attributes could help too

Answer (score 0):

Something about this doesn't look right. Usually the `has_many` reference is plural. It's possible your naming scheme is messing with Rails' opinionated magic.

Also why would `headoffice` have a field called `headoffice_id`? Wouldn't it just have a field called `id`? Finally, one nitpick, it should be called `head_office` not `headoffice`. And `tse` is not a good name either. What is `tse`? Spell it out if you can and form it in a manner that can be singular or plural. Rails works much better if you follow these simple naming guidelines.

https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e

See the simple example below:

post.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :post
```

To access a post's comments you'd type the following:

```
Post.first.comment.body
```

Or if you're uncertain about a post having a comment you'd say:

```
Post.first.try(:comment).try(:body)
```

Comment: Yea. looks like the issue is with naming convention. Just working around on the fix.

Comment: Once you come to a conclusion please pick an answer from this page or answer your own question. This will help future struggling developers with a same or similar problem as you. Also feel free to upvote any answers you found helpful. 

Comment: Oops sorry.  That occur was because of using Private method in middle of controller. Bad me!